# Recursive database call in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, recursive-query

I am using ASP Classic and I want to have real time label on my page indicating how many users are currently using my page.

Scenario:
I have this label:

```
Current # of Users: 53     ---> 53 being the real time label
```

and I want it to update itself when someone comes in or out.

They say it's called Recursive function,but I have no idea how I should do this.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set-up a simple monitor using a mix of JavaScript and Classic ASP, or using JQuery to AJAX a call to a querying function in your ASP code.

Personally I would use just JavaScript if you're looking for something fairly lightweight (after all, the whole JQuery library would have to be fed down the pipe to the client browser, and, though fairly small, it's still ~95k that could be put to better use!).

I would set-up a standard VBScript/JScript page to pull the info from the database first.

Set-up a `div` on your page to contain the info:

```
<div id="userCount"></div>
```

Next, use something like the following function to pull the info from the ASP page into the `div` you created...

```
/*
    AJAX extension to allow dynamic interaction between pages.

    This section initialises the variable used to store the XMLHTTP request object.
*/
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari...
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

/*
    ajaxPage
        Posts a request to the scripted specified page.
    Parameters:
        postPage (string) - The page to be opened.
        paramList (string) - The list of parameters/values to be applied to the page.
    Usage:
        var targetBlock = document.getElementById("resultDiv");
        targetBlock.innerHTML = ajaxPage("resultsPage.asp","calcVal=545")
    Description:
        This routine uses the xmlhttp requesting tools within JavaScript to act as an intermediary between
        script and page.  Specify all paramters in the paramList by separating with an ampersand (&).
*/
function ajaxPage(postPage, paramList) {
    xmlhttp.open("POST",postPage,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(paramList);
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Then set-up a [JavaScript timer](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) in your page header like so:

```
<script>
    // Every 10 seconds execute the following...
    setInterval('document.getElementById("userCount").innerHTML = ajaxPage("myAspCounterScript.asp", "")', 10000);
</script>
```

Please note that I can only comment on my own posts as yet (under 50 rep, but feel free to ask questions)...

Comment: Not sure why would javascript-only scripts be considered lightweight... even fairly.

It's a 95k file, yes... but exactly _what_ can you put in it's place? An image is at least 400k, and an average .NET auto-generated script is 10k at the least.

Not to mention the development enhances that jQuery provides, and all the community support therein. 
Nonetheless, ... nice answer. Almost an hour ahead of me. :\

Comment: This is a single little piece of JavaScript - several bytes long.  It keeps the page lean.  If you're not going to be using large sections of JQuery then why bother including them...?  This is also **Classic ASP** not ASP.NET.  I left the comments in as a guide - they could be taken out, and even the line breaks...

Comment: Aye, I was aware that this is a Classic ASP topic, as can be seen from the tags. That was just an example. Dull, stupid, but an example nonetheless.
My point was (thought cleary not clear enough) that even in simple applications, jQuery's development enhancements _can_ (even if you disagree) be quite useful, mainly if (andnot assuming that you are) starting to develop now.
And I wasn't criticizing your answer,... it was just an addendum.

Comment: Okay, then; on the theory that you presented above,do you like Microsoft Office?  If you do, then do you install every last part of it or only the parts that you actually need?  My programming training comes from a time when memory was small and expensive, and speed was a priority.  As I see it, speed still is a premium thing, especially when you're talking about someone else's computer - you don't know what's out there.  I know a guy, for instance, who still has an old 56K modem (so you're talking about a download rate of about 33K).  Do snipers use machine guns? Nope...

Comment: No, even if I _loved_ Microsoft Office, I wouldn't install all that is within it, but I can't see why it fits in this context: jQuery is _not_ mandatory. If you consider 95k to be a big file, then images would be quite counterfitting, no? Still... Hell, Your answer was good enough. _All I said was an addendum_.

Comment: :o)  Thank-you.  Even images I do tend to compress as much as possible.  I've seen some terrible sites that rely on massive uncompressed images...  But yes - I know what you're saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55772/discussion-between-eric-wu-and-paul).